# How to use the proposed ECMAscript class syntax with React and Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-next

I am trying to learn the proposed class syntax for ecmascript and using it with React, i have successfully rendered components with es6 using babel with webpack. Now i want to use instance properties inside classes which are declared outside of the constructor. For eg:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
   super(props)
  }

  property1= "new property"; 
  func1= ()=>{
   }
  }
```

I am getting the error "unexpected token" on 'property1' and 'func1' while trying to do something like this. also, i am using the babel presets for react and babel-preset-env plugins in webpack.

I want to limit the use of "this" keyword inside my class, so i thought the newer es7 classes could acheive that, how can i do this? any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1: as suggested in the answers, 
i included the "babel-preset-stage-2" preset , and i was able to include the variables outside of the constructor in the class, but have to use 'this' to reference them.

Comment: member (private) properties are not supported in es7 AFAIK.  You probably need an extra babel plugin if you want to use them.

Comment: shouldn't this be `var property1= "new property"; `

Comment: nope, doesn't work either, i am now trying the 'stage-2' preset and will update

Comment: Re your edits: Just emphasizing again: This is not ES7.

Comment: Your "Edit 2" is a whole new question. Please ask it as one. Questions on SO are not meant to be moving targets. The question you asked here, originally, is answered by the answers below.

Comment: sure ,will add a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That syntax isn't "ES7" (by which I assume you mean [ES2016](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html), aka the 7th edition). In fact, it's not even ES2017. It's still a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). It *might* make ES2018 if a couple of implementations get done in time for it reach Stage 4 before the cutoff.

To use it with Babel, enable the [`stage-3` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) or the [specific plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) for that feature (`transform-class-properties`).

Comment: thanks, i was missing this part, but i tried with the 'stage-3' preset  and still getting the same error, updated the question with the details...

Comment: @vikrant: They seem to be running behind (at least in the version they deploy for their [REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhA9gWwA7IHYFMsBdoB6AKhwA988ATGAJRzGHwDoUNs98SjoBvAFDRowbBHwAnAK7NkEgBToJydBACU_IcOJEIU9DgVKV6rQF8BW4wYn54ARmgBeaACJcAd2jXDd1wG5LYQAzKSxgRxd5DScAPn4zQIsBUSxxEWdoTzgkNExcAkDUiGQQHBYQZABzeWAWH1sHNX8gA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0)), it's in the `stage-2`preset even though it's at Stage 3 now.

Comment: @vikrant: Looks like it's that way on npm as well, just running behind is all (one reason to use the specific plugin for the features you want).

Comment: yup, the plugin is working , i created variables inside class, but for some reason the 'stage-2' preset is giving a lot of errors,so i am not including in the webpack.
 also when i declare a function inside class, and then call that function without 'this' keyword, i am getting a error in crome console: 
"A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the react-dom.development.js", but if i call that function like 'this.func1" then there are no errors...

Comment: @vikrant: That would be unrelated. Side note re the original code: I suggest either using `;`, or relying on automatic semicolon insertion, but not mix-and-match. (And strongly recommend providing the `;` rather than relying on an *error-correction* mechanism.)

Comment: noted. i like to use the semicolons , it makes the code look good to me and more readable

Comment: working with 'stage-2' also, just checked , for some reason the preset didn't install the first time , have to install it again.

Answer (score 2):

You will need the correct babel plugin for this.

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

More information: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: would this work if i only use the 'stage-3' preset in webpack?